# How Do I Remove Boot, Home and HP tools From the devices menu?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

My computer crashed. [This Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475914/can-kde-cause-ubuntu-to-crash) Will show you how. Now I have Home,Boot  and hp tools in my devices menu.Here is a screenshot of it[image]

How Do I remove them. I got all my files back but I cannot understand how do I remove them. I don´t want them. Thank You :)

Here Is A screenshot of my Gparted. Can you tell which HOME and BOOT I can remove?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are different partitions on your drives. The `BOOT` partition likely contains the boot files, the `HP_TOOLS` likely contains HP QuickWeb (or other tools), and the `HOME` partition seems to be your main Ubuntu partition.

Note that it is only safe to remove the `HP_TOOLS` partition, since you need the `BOOT` partition to boot up your computer. To remove the partition, use GParted Partition Editor.

Comment: Is there any way I can hide them?

Comment: Not sure on that. KDE's Dolphin has an option, but I don't remember about Nautilus. Note that if you hide `HOME`, it will be a little difficult to get to the root of the partition.

Comment: You Dont See. I reinstalled ubuntu and I have 2 home and 2 boot partitions.

Comment: Ah, that's a bit of a...mess. Open up GParted Partition Editor, and identify the unused/old partitions. There's a good chance that one of the two don't have a lock icon, and this one is the old one (Make sure you unmount the partitions first by clicking on the "eject" icon.). Remove those partitions.

Comment: Also, make sure you have a Live CD/USB handy in case something goes wrong.